# Error testing Restful API in Laravel using PHPUnit

Tags: php, json, api, rest, laravel

Our team has created a Restful API using laravel. We are doing unit testing on the api using PHPUNIT but encountered a problem on testing a POST request.

Here is the code:

```
public function create_new_account()
{
    $account = array (
        'accountName'=>$this->fake->word,
        'contactName'=>$this->fake->name,
        'contactEmail'=>$this->fake->email,
        'address'=>$this->fake->sentence
    );
    $accounts = json_encode($account);
    $this->call('POST','accounts',$accounts);
    $this->assertResponseOk();

}
```

This tests if we can create an account using API but I'm always getting an errror

```
    1) ApiServicesTest::create_new_account
ErrorException: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/mcx-api/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php on line 421 and defined

/var/www/mcx-api/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php:1999
/var/www/mcx-api/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php:421
/var/www/mcx-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/CrawlerTrait.php:775
/var/www/mcx-api/tests/ApiServicesTest.php:35
```

When you test the api using a client like httprequester/postman it is working fine. The api is required to be passed a JSON data so if I passed the array the api is inserting null values. But when I converted the data to json I get the error above. When I tried dd($accounts) here is the output

```
"{"accountName":"rerum","contactName":"Ms. Mireille Veum Jr.","contactEmail":"Lindgren.Damaris@gmail.com","address":"Vel quidem consectetur nemo excepturi quod."}"
```

which means data is converted to json format and should be accepted by the api however I don't get what laravel is complaining. Can somebody point me to where I'm doing it wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending the json as the content.

```
$this->call('POST', 'accounts', [], [], [], [], $accounts)
```

Comment: Thank you. @user3158900 can you give a brief explanation on why the format is like that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry I got it now. This is because of this syntax of a function ->public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)